# What versions of HBase and Hive are compatible?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

What versions of HBase and Hive are compatible with each other?

I am currently running HBase 0.96 and HIVE 0.12 and am wondering if the following error is due to compatibility:

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient

Edit: Changed 0.9.6 to 0.96

Answer (score 0):

Try to work out with HBase and hive stable version.

hive:

http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hive/stable/

HBase:
http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/hbase/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Hive 0.12 and HBase 0.96 are compatible. Try installing them with [Ambari](http://ambari.apache.org/) or taking one of the distros (Hortonworks 2, Cloudera 5)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can check that on the pom.xml file of your Hive distribution, as Hive is dependent of Hbase, not the other way around.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/pom.xml

If you are having troubles making all the different versions work together, you can get a Cloudera or IBM (free) product, that provides a Hadoop ecosystem with all these components already tested and working together.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/biginsights/

http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to compile the latest versions from source code.

Answer (score -1):

When you use CDH (Cloudera's Distribution including Hadoop), you won't worry anymore. It is a free version that contains Apache Hadoop and other components you need in one bundle. No compatibility issues anymore.